# How to connect a MySQL database using HikariCP and Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, wildfly-10, hikaricp

I really need your help because I CAN`T understand why it is so hard to connect to a database using Hikari in a Wildfly-10.1.0.Final deployed application. I created the data source ***java:/mydbname_v2*** and Wildfly can connect to the database using it's data. I'm also able to connect database using Sequel Pro, so obviously the problem is this Hikari connection code.

BTW, the line ***System.out.println( "DataSource: " + ds );*** prints null for ds object...

This is so elementary, what I am missing? Here is my code, btw (I tried the three "setDataSouce's" method below):

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    //config.setDataSourceJNDI( "java:/mydbname_v2" );
    //config.setDataSourceClassName( "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" );
    config.setDriverClassName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://myhost.com:3306/mydbname_v2");
    config.setUsername("myuser");
    config.setPassword("mypassword");

    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    try {
        DataSource ds = config.getDataSource();
        System.out.println( "DataSource: " + ds );
        System.out.println( "DataSource - string: " + ds.toString() );
        if ( ds == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return config.getDataSource().getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks

I solved the problem using:

```
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:/mydbname_v2");    

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSource( ds );
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");      

        return config.getDataSource().getConnection();
```